# How to create a shopping cart

Tags: jquery, css, html, web

I'm looking to create a shopping cart type part for my website and was just wondering the best way to go about it, such as local storage/ session storage or maybe saving it in a database?

Comment: Might be worth posting a bit more information and context on what your requirements are. `shopping cart type part` isn't overly descriptive. Try a few methods out, and come back with a more specific problem as this question is very generalised.

Comment: You will need a database at some point. Storing transaction information on your client's browser is problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many tutorials you can find. Try googling `shopping cart tutorials` and such.

[Here](http://www.qualitycodes.com/tutorial.php?articleid=25&title=Tutorial-Building-a-shopping-cart-in-PHP) and [here](http://jameshamilton.eu/content/simple-php-shopping-cart-tutorial)  is an example of a tutorial website creating a shopping cart system. Most people seem to be using PHP and MySQL for it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd use PHP sessions for the shopping cart, as I see no practical use in storing the shopping cart between several sessions (visits to your website). However I'd probably store purchased items in a database to provide purchase history for customers.

My answer is very vague because of the nature of your question. Without a very clear problem it is hard to provide an exact answer. For future questions, try to narrow your specific problem down and post some code or describe what you've tried already.

Good luck!